# Call Function within const javascript react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, geofire

I'm new to react native and javascript. I've come from java and android dev.
I'm looking to call a function within a const, but I just get a load of errors no matter what way I try it.

I'm getting the error :

```
this.collectionUpdate is not a function
```

**MainScreen:**

```
 onCollectionUpdate = (doc) => {
    const items = [];

    doc.forEach((doc)=> {
        console.log("doc received");
        const {Name, imageDownloadUrl,Location} = doc.data();

        items.push({
            key: doc.id,
            doc, //DocumentSnapshot
            Name,
            imageDownloadUrl,
            Location,

        });
    });

    this.setState({
        items,
        loading: false,
    });
}




componentDidMount() {

    const geoQuery = geoFirestore.query({
        center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(10.38, 2.41),
        radius: 10.5
    });

    const onReadyRegistration = geoQuery.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('GeoFirestoreQuery has loaded and fired all other events for initial data');
    });


    const onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on('key_entered', function(key, doc, distance) {
        console.log(key + ' entered query at ' + doc.coordinates.latitude
            + ',' + doc.Name
            + ',' + doc.coordinates.longitude
            + ' (' + distance + ' km from center)')

        this.onCollectionUpdate(doc)



    });

    this.onCollectionUpdate = this.onCollectionUpdate.bind(this);
}
```

I know this is probably not working for me as I don't know enough in javascript to understand what I'm doing wrong but, I will start doing courses in Javascript soon to get a better understanding. But I would be very appreciative for anyone who could show me where I'm going wrong. I feel it's because I'm trying to call a function inside a const?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about the `const`, it's about the `function`. Functions written with the keyword `function` create a new scope for `this`. When you use `this` inside a `function`, you're looking at a different `this` from that outside of it.

```
geoQuery.on('key_entered', function(key, doc, distance) {
    this.onCollectionUpdate(doc) // wrong "this"
})
```

One easy way to solve it is to just use a `=>` function here:

```
geoQuery.on('key_entered', (key, doc, distance) => {
    this.onCollectionUpdate(doc) // correct "this"
})
```

Comment: Hi Lazar, Thank you for your quick answer, after making the change you recommended. now it says doc.forEach is not a function.

Comment: @AndrewIrwin that would indicate that doc is not an array, log the value to make sure you are passing that argument properly and it is the shape you expect

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak ok thank you very much! Appreciate it!